# Visibility with throw and shared objects

Tags: c++, object, visibility, shared, throw

I'm porting a code from Windows to CentOS but I'm confronting with a problem that I've never seen before.

Given that function declaration (there are many more) :

```
byte getValueInt8() const throw(.../*Exception*/);
```

I get this error:

```
error: expected type-specifier before ‘...’ token unsigned short getValueInt8() const throw(.../*Exception*/);
```

Of course I've checked the internet and I've found that it is a visibility problem in shared objects.

This website https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility explains that but I had already done this when I read it.

My defines are:

```
#if defined(_MSC_VER)
#include <winsock2.h>
   #ifdef MFTINTERFACE_EXPORTS
      #define EXPORT_IMPORT __declspec(dllexport)
   #else
      #define EXPORT_IMPORT __declspec(dllimport)
   #endif
#elif defined(_GCC)
   #include <arpa/inet.h>
   #include "CmnSocketsDef.h"
   #include "CmnDefs.h"
   #define EXPORT_IMPORT __attribute__((visibility("default")))   
#else
   #define EXPORT_IMPORT
   #define IMPORT
   #pragma warning Unknown dynamic link import/EXPORT_IMPORT semantics.
#endif
```

Of course, all EXPORT_IMPORT are well set in my code.

The code, before modification compiles in Windows.

Comment: `throw(...)` means that the function can throw *any* exception. That's similar to not having an exception specification at all.

Answer (score 2):

`throw(...)` as an exception specification isn't legal c++.

I can only assume you've encountered a Microsoft <strike>abomination</strike> extension.

You'll need to remove it. In any case the only exception specifier that makes any sense in reality is `nothrow` (or `throw()` if you're using an ancient compiler).

Indeed, here's the smoking gun:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wfa0edys.aspx

proposal to deprecate:

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3051.html

Comment: Ok thank you very much ! I delete all these throws then !

Comment: @Render yes, delete all the `throw(...)` statements. leave the `throw()` ones as they mandate that the function must not throw anything. You can convert those ones to `nothrow` because `throw()` is deprecated.

Comment: Actually, I won't. I just seen with different files that after "..." there are other informations than /*Exception*/. It's a structure type so I throw it. I just modified a piece of code and it works

Comment: @Render. if you uncomment `Exception` you're telling the compiler that that function is guaranteeing to never throw anything other than `Exception`. If it does, the program will `abort()`. It's actually better to remove exception specifications altogether. They are deprecated because it was a mistake to ever put them in the c++ standard. http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3051.html

Comment: Exception is a structure with a string for a message inside. These exceptions are handled with "try catch" and return false in the catch. Will `abort()` will be called anyway ?

Comment: @Render if something other than `Exception` is thrown (e.g. a std::runtime_error, std::logic_error or std::system_error, your program will `abort()` in production. This is probably not a good thing. Better to have no exception specifications rather than deprecated (and dangerous) ones that permit only certain exceptions.